# Unsupported method Distinct in linq using the Mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I need to get the count of the distinct values in a select using the mongodb driver and linq. I made a groupby and then I'm trying to make the distinct but I'm always getting "unsupported method". How can I avoid it? I have no problems when I'm making other operations like average or sum. Is the problem that i'm making a select into another select?

```
queryGroupby = whereQuery.GroupBy(x => x.CheckinDate.ToString("yyyy MMM"));

var querySelect = queryGroupby
                  .Select(g => new Statistic()
                   {
                    HotelsCount = g.Select(g => g.HoId).Distinct().Count(),
                    Key = g.Key,
                    TotalBookingsAmount = g.Sum(g => g.GrossTotal) + g.Sum(g => g.Taxes),
                    BookingsCount = g.Count(g => true),
                    TotalBookedDays = g.Sum(g => g.StayDays),
                    AvgWindowStay = g.Average(g => g.StayDays),
                    AvgBookingsAmount = g.Average(g => g.GrossTotal) + g.Average(g => g.Taxes)
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use Mongodb aggregate for such complex queries, I am not sure what are you trying to do here, but I will show you how this should be done with c# mongodb driver.

Ideally, you should be using [aggregate framework group by function](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluentExtensions_Group__3.htm), now if you find the doc hard to read, it is basically defining a extension method to `IAggregateFluent`, which takes two parameters, the first is an expression to your group key, the second is an expression that takes the group by original result, and return the projection for that result, in your case, the first expression is your `queryGroupBy`, and the second expression is your `querySelect`.

I am guessing your object type is Booking, hence the generic `Aggregate<Booking>` below

```
var result = await _collection.Aggregate<Booking>()
                .Group(e => e.CheckinDate.ToString("yyyy MMM"), // group by date
                            result => new Statistic()  //result is the group result, new Statistic is your projection of the result.
                   {
                    HotelsCount = g.Select(g => g.HoId).Distinct().Count(),
                    Key = g.Key,
                    TotalBookingsAmount = g.Sum(g => g.GrossTotal) + g.Sum(g => g.Taxes),
                    BookingsCount = g.Count(g => true),
                    TotalBookedDays = g.Sum(g => g.StayDays),
                    AvgWindowStay = g.Average(g => g.StayDays),
                    AvgBookingsAmount = g.Average(g => g.GrossTotal) + g.Average(g => g.Taxes)
                    })
                .ToListAsync();
```